# Android OnItemClickListener not working in Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have looked at all the questions about this on this site, and tried all the solutions, and nothing has worked, so I'm making this question in order to post my specific code.

I have a fragment extending ListFragment (android.support.v4.app.ListFragment) which contains three buttons and a ListView, the ListView DOES NOT have any custom views that could steal focus, it is simply a ListView that was created using an ArrayAdapter. The onCreateView() method looks like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scoring, container, false);

    scrabbleGame = new Scrabble();
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    ArrayList<String> playerList = bundle.getStringArrayList("Player List");

    for(String playerName : playerList){
        Player player = new Player(playerName, scrabbleGame);
        scrabbleGame.addPlayer(player);
    }



    players = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, scrabbleGame.getPlayerNames());
    players.setAdapter(adapter);
    players.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Click registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String playerName = players.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Player player = scrabbleGame.getPlayerByName(playerName);
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(player, scrabbleGame);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

When I click an item in the list, nothing happens, the event/listener is never triggered, it never hits that line. No errors come up. Just simply nothing happens.

**I would not be asking this question if I had found a solution in one of the other questions about it on this site, so please do not mark this as duplicate.**

***I've fixed it. Changed it to extend a normal fragment and now it works***

Comment: Not a real solution since i can't manage to reproduce it, but did you tought at simply creating a custom adapter and set your onclick to the container when creating the holder?

Comment: Great.. if you use ListViewFragment you can try this players.setOnItemClickListener(new View.OnItemClickListener()

Comment: what does your listview contain?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. Was solved by adding the following to the LinearLayout in the list item XML:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```